# How to auto switch on/off precise location automatically, programmatically for Google Maps?

Tags: shell, google-maps, command-line, gps-tracking, bash

Is there an `am` command line or similar that permits do turn off/on Google Maps precise location?

Ideally, could be a wrapper script in shell to enable precise mode, then when quitting maps, setting back to disabled mode.

Or maybe an `am` command to save settings states before/after use.

Any hint please? Open to alternatives way.

Searched web + here with no good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a starter, with a rooted device, it's possible to do something like:

```
#!/system/bin/sh

# Check if the device is rooted
if [ $(id -u) -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "This script requires root access."
    exit 1
fi

# Retrieve maps's pid
mapspid=$(pgrep -f com.google.android.apps.maps)

# Check if precise GPS location is enabled
is_enabled=$(settings get secure location_providers_allowed | grep 'gps')

if [ -z "$mapspid" ] && [ ! -z "$is_enabled" ]; then
    # maps is NOT running and precise gps is enabled
    # Disable precise GPS location 
    settings put secure location_providers_allowed '-gps'
else
    # maps is running
    # Enable precise GPS location
    [ -z "$is_enabled" ] && settings put secure location_providers_allowed '+gps'
fi
```

This can be put in `cron` every minutes or every 30 seconds.

Another solution would be to use a wrapper script to run Maps, then when launched, put setting back to 'not precise'.

**Untested**.